# how can I run an app in sandbox?

Tags: mac, sandbox

I wanted to play some games found on internet (not the Mac store) but I was afraid those could have a virus inside. As such I wanted to run them in a sandbox where they could just read files from their folder.

I have found [some questions about sandbox-exec](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248407/sandbox-on-mac-os-x) but pretty old and Apple says it is a deprecated command (though I don't care as long as it works).

```
$ cat myscript.sh
#!/bin/bash

$ cat perms.sb 
(version 1)
(deny default)
(debug all)

$ sandbox-exec -f perms.sb ./myscript.sh 
sandbox-exec: execvp() of './myscript.sh' failed: Operation not permitted
```

**What are the minimum perms to run a program?**

`debug` doesn't seem to add anything useful. Note that this command works if I replace `deny default` with `allow default` but **I can't find what `allow default` allows**. For instance it allows to write to a folder outside of the one from the script.

On a side note Apple says that `sandbox-exec` is deprecated and we should include sandboxing in our app... this is useful for apps from the Mac store and/or our own apps but what about something else downloaded from internet?

Final thought: would there be a smart way to set perms with `chmod` so that the program cannot access/write stuff from my user?

Comment: I also interested in the answer. Especially how I can limit the application's network access? Like it cannot to call any internal (LAN) resources, but can access to the Internet.